# JSON: Find value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have JSON with the following structure:

```
[
    {
        "Str1" : "Val1",
        "Str2" : "Val2",
    },
    {
        ...
    },
    {
        "Str7" : "cat",
        "Str8" : "black",
    },
    {
        ...
    }
]
```

I now need to get the value `black`. Everything I know is the value `cat`.
So I need to iterate and look for `cat`. When `cat` is found, give me the other (2nd) value of this specific array, in this case `black`.

My approach was this:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON('[{"Str1" : "Val1","Str2" : "Val2"},{"Str7" : "cat","Str8" : "black"}]');


$.each(obj, function(key,value) {
    if(value == "cat"){
        console.log("cat found"); // not triggered
    }
});
```

But `cat` was not even found.

Comment: Just as an FYI, those are objects within a single array ***not*** individual arrays...

Comment: @War10ck: I've changed that.

Comment: Do the missing objects have properties `Str3, Str4`, `Str5, Str6`...?

Comment: As you can see it's `obj[0].Str7 === 'cat'` or `value.Str7 === 'cat'`. You're comparing the entire object to `cat`.

Comment: When you are looping, you are looping the array element, not the object itself, you need to go deeper. You should nest your loops.

Comment: @Downvoters: What's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and see what you get:

```
$.each(obj, function(key,value) {
    if (value === "cat") {
        console.log("cat found"); // not triggered
    }
    else
        {
        // See what you do have, if it isn't the string "cat"
        console.log("What is it??", value);
        }
});
```

First understand your data structures and what you have.  That is what the above is for.

---

Then try this:

```
$.each(obj, function(key,value) {
    $.each(value, function(key, value2)
        {
        if (value2 === "cat"){
            console.log("cat found");
            console.log("Cat was found in the object", value);
        }
    });
});
```

This will find the string `"cat"`.  Then you know that the object referenced by the variable `value` contains the what you want.

Answer (score 2):

When `$.each` iterates over the array, the `key` is returned as the numeric index (`0`, `1`, etc.) and the value is returned as `[object Object]`. To solve this you need to first iterate over the array and then use `$.each()` on the object value:

```
var arr = $.parseJSON('[{"Str1" : "Val1","Str2" : "Val2"},{"Str7" : "cat","Str8" : "black"}]');

for(var a = 0, len = arr.length; a < len; a++) {
    $.each(arr[a], function(key,value) {
        alert(key + " - " + value);
        if(value == "cat"){
            console.log("cat found"); // not triggered
        }
    }); 
}
```

In this example `arr[a]` will be each object as you iterate through the array. For the first iteration `arr[a]` is equivalent to:

```
{
    "Str1": "Val1",
    "Str2": "Val2"
}
```

So running `$.each()` over the value of `arr[a]` will result in two iterations with the following property outputs:

1. `key = "Str1"`, `value = "Val1"`
2. `key = "Str2"`, `value = "Val2"`

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over an array, not an object. So you should do like this:

```
$.each(obj, function(key,value) {
    $.each(value, function(propertyName, valueOfProperty) {
        if(valueOfProperty == "cat") {
            console.log(value); // logs the object that contains "cat"
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code referenced from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
JSON.parse('[{"Str1" : "Val1","Str2" : "Val2"},{"Str7" : "cat","Str8" : "black"}]', function(k,v){
    if(v==='cat') console.log('found');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try this as it works for me .

```
 var obj = $.parseJSON('[{"Str1" : "Val1","Str2" : "Val2"},{"Str7" : cat","Str8": "black"}]');

$.each(obj, function(key1,value) {
    for(var key in value) {
        if(value[key] == "cat") {
            console.log("cat found");
            break;
        }
    }   
});
```